# oncoming <animal> <human>

Tags: meaning

[gutenberg.org](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/21254/21254-h/21254-h.htm):
**(1)** *The hunter points it in a general way in the direction of **the oncoming beast**, pulls the trigger and hopes for the best*.
Does "*oncoming beast*" sound correct?
If not, then why not?

Can we also say "*oncoming man*"?
For example (my own sentence):
**(2)** *I saw **an oncoming man***.
Does "*oncoming man*" sound correct?
If not, then why not?

Answer (score 1):

You can say both, but approaching sounds more natural.

"oncoming animal": https://www.google.com/search?q=%22oncoming+animal%22&biw=1309&bih=632&sxsrf=ALiCzsYaafNhpMjRSkFhecHDOMYAAYw9tw%3A1672790788795&ei=BMO0Y_3zL9_SytMPuIC0kA8&ved=0ahUKEwj9hf-lz6z8AhVfqXIEHTgADfIQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=%22oncoming+animal%22&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzIKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzIKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzIKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzIKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzIKCAAQRxDWBBCwA0oECEEYAEoECEYYAFAAWABg14ACaAJwAXgAgAEAiAEAkgEAmAEAyAEGwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-serp

"oncoming man": https://www.google.com/search?q=%22oncoming+man%22&sxsrf=ALiCzsbrbklmbvK2Vwb2U5DRkDW67yEPTQ:1672790784104&ei=AMO0Y_b8BbqoytMPnvu94A4&start=0&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwj2_OCjz6z8AhU6lHIEHZ59D-w4HhDy0wN6BAgDEAQ&biw=1309&bih=632&dpr=2.2

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does, oncoming is great here, an adjective describing what is happening.

Check [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oncoming) bullet 1a):

> oncoming:
>
> coming nearer in time or space

Your example

> I saw an oncoming man.

I'd rather say  *I saw a man approaching* while the plural sounds fine *I saw oncoming men*